# no entiendo porque me genera el error luego de terminar el código java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

buenos días ando en esto de la programación y al desarrollar un ejercicio tengo un error el cual no se como solucionarlo, estaría muy agradecido con la ayuda que me puedan brindar, con me deja ejecutar el programa hasta que pide la cantidad de datos a registrar para iniciar el ciclo y luego al pedir el primer dato dentro del ciclo me manda un error

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Reto1 {

    private static int f;
    private static float interes,saldo,interescuenta[],interestotal,saldototal;
    private static float saldocuenta[];
    private static int tipoCuenta[];
    private static long numcuenta[];
    private static LocalDate fechaCuenta[]=new LocalDate[10];
    
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        
        int cantidadCuentas=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Digite la cantidad de cuentas"));
        for(f=1;f <= cantidadCuentas;f++){
         
          Scanner teclado= new Scanner (System.in); /* permite cargar datos por teclado*/
          numcuenta[f]= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Digite el numero de la cuenta "));
          String dateString="12/12/1987"; 
          dateString =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "digite fecha:");
          fechaCuenta[f]=LocalDate.parse(dateString);
          tipoCuenta[f]=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Digite el tipo de cuenta"));;
        
          if(tipoCuenta.equals("1")){
                       interes=(float)0.015;
                   }else if(tipoCuenta.equals("2")){
                       interes=(float)0.017;
                       break;
                   }else{
                       interes=(float)0.016;
                   }
       
         System.out.print(""); 
         saldo=teclado.nextFloat();
         interescuenta[f]=saldo*interes;
         saldocuenta[f]=saldo+interescuenta[f];
         interestotal=interestotal+interescuenta[f];
         saldototal=saldototal+saldocuenta[f];
        }
       
        for(f=0;f<cantidadCuentas;f++){
            
            System.out.print(numcuenta[f]);
            System.out.print(interescuenta[f]);
            System.out.print(saldocuenta[f]);
        }
           System.out.print(interestotal);
           System.out.print(saldototal);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Te falto inicializar todos los arrays.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido.Los arrays tiene tamaño estatico es decir antes de usarlos debes declarar el tamaño que tendra, al igual que lo hace con el array fechaCuenta ,el resto de arrays debe tener un tamaño declarado,de no querer manejarlo asi,puedes hacer uso de un ArrayList